# Git subtree push always fails

Tags: git, merge, push, subtree

Trying to use git subtree to share common library files across multiple projects. Here's the problem I keep encountering.

1) Add subtree so "lib" subdirectory of my project is coming from lib-dk repository.

```
$ git subtree add --prefix=lib --squash git@bitbucket.org:dwknight/lib-dk.git master
```

2) Make changes to files in "lib"

3) commit changes to main project repo

```
$ git commit -am "update project"
```

4) push updates to main project repo

```
$ git push origin master
```

5) push changes in "lib" back to "lib-dk" repo

```
$ git subtree push --prefix=lib git@bitbucket.org:dwknight/lib-dk.git master
git push using:  git@bitbucket.org:dwknight/lib-dk.git master
To git@bitbucket.org:dwknight/lib-dk.git
 ! [rejected]        f455c24a79447c6e3fe1690f5709357b7f96828a -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:dwknight/lib-dk.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

6) I get this rejection even if nothing has changed in the lib-dk repo. When I try a pull, it acts like something has but I'm able to update via the pull. Still the push continues to be rejected.

Comment: I have no experience using the `subtree` command but the `--squash` operation looks like a `rebase` option.  What does it do?  If it's modifying the branch history somehow then that could cause this problem.

Answer (score 2):

When I try this without the `--squash` option to `git subtree add`, it works.  I think, as the commenter suggested, the `--squash` is fiddling with the history in an unhelpful way.

Answer (score 0):

You might need use `git add -A .` then `git commit` rather than `git commit -am <message>`

since `-A` in `git-add` would do:

```
   -A, --all, --no-ignore-removal
       Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching <pathspec> but also where the
       index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working
       tree.

       If no <pathspec> is given when -A option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated
       (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).
```

on the other hand, the `-a` in `git-commit` would do (not much details be given by the man page):

```
   -a, --all
       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files
       you have not told Git about are not affected.
```

[this](https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844#.owzi6xh6d) might be helpful. The author called `git add -A .` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `--squash` when you added a subtree you have to do `git subtree pull --prefix=prefix remote branch --squash` before you push